# oracle: sort by date and timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I select some data from three tables using `union` then I would like to sort them by date and timestamp (descending):

```
select reportname as name, convert_to_char(a.date) AS created,
....
from table1 

UNION
select reportname as name, convert_to_char(a.date) AS created,
....
from table2

UNION
select reportname as name, convert_to_char(a.date) AS created,
....
from table3

order by created desc;
```

convert_to_char is implemented as follow:

```
create or replace function convert_to_char(myDate date) 
RETURN varchar IS
BEGIN
return TO_CHAR(cast (myDate as timestamp) at local, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM');
END;
```

the result of the sorted data I get looks like this:

```
created
------------------
2017-04-12 16:07:07 +02:00
2017-04-13 09:00:01 +02:00
2017-04-13 09:00:40 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:06:17 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:08:37 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:07:31 +02:00
2017-04-13 09:00:25 +02:00
2017-04-13 09:00:25 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:09:07 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:08:20 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:08:06 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:06:48 +02:00
```

But I expect the following sorting result:

```
created
------------------
2017-04-13 09:00:40 +02:00
2017-04-13 09:00:25 +02:00
2017-04-13 09:00:25 +02:00
2017-04-13 09:00:01 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:09:07 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:08:37 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:08:20 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:08:06 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:07:31 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:07:07 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:06:48 +02:00
2017-04-12 16:06:17 +02:00
```

any idea how to get the expected sorting result?

thank you in advance.

Comment: `sort by`?  In Oracle?

Comment: Why not use `ORDER BY a.date`

Comment: I have updated to "order by". sort by was typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort them first and then select

```
select name, created 
from 
(select reportname as name, convert_to_char(a.date) AS created, a.date,
 ....
from table1 

UNION
select reportname as name, convert_to_char(a.date) AS created, a.date
....
from table2

UNION
select reportname as name, convert_to_char(a.date) AS created, a.date
....
from table3
order by a.date desc);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select name, convert_to_char(created) from (
    select reportname as name,  date AS created,
    ....
    from table1 

    UNION
    select reportname as name, date AS created,
    ....
    from table2

    UNION
    select reportname as name, date AS created,
    ....
    from table3
) t
order by created desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your syntax for the UNION queries is wrong. You can only create the alias on the first SELECT. The UNION versions all just select fields with the same data type.

Second, by doing the unions in a subquery, you can then select directly from that and it will order just fine.

```
WITH TotalTable AS (
  select reportname as name, convert_to_char(a.date) AS created,
  ....
  from table1 
  UNION
  select reportname, convert_to_char(a.date),
  ....
  from table2
  UNION
  select reportname, convert_to_char(a.date),
  ....
  from table3)
SELECT reportname, created FROM TotalTable
ORDER BY created DESC
```